# How to archive DONE tasks while keeping their tree structure with org-agenda-bulk-action?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, archive-mode, org-refile

I am able to select the tasks that I want to archive by doing:

1. `C-c a T DONE|CANCELLED RET`
2. `* B`

But then none of the bulk options match my needs.

- `$` remove the selected tasks and put them flatly into a `ToDo.org_archive` file
- `A` keep the tasks within `ToDo.org` under an archived form
- `r` is similar to `$`

I'd like to remove the selected tasks and put them into an org file where their classification (the tree structure) would be preserved.

Can the `f` option allow to do this, and if yes, what would be the function?